# How do I lock some columns and some rows in a Libreoffice Calc worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, freeze, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

I am using Libreoffice Calc 5.2.0.4.

I am building an appointment book. This book has many sheets/ pages.

I am not experienced, so I was experimenting on different sheets. And now I have three different sheets and don't even know how I got there. Can someone tell me what happened?

Freezing Panes0 - Seems to be my original sheet. The only thing I did consciously was to freeze the leftmost column.
[Freezing Panes0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w1pp.png)

Freezing Panes1 - When I pulled on the top left gray line by accident, I discovered it created some sort of frozen pane. But I don't know how I got here. That gray line doesn't appear on my other spreadsheets.

[Freezing Panes1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug1c7.png)

Freezing Panes2 - I arrived here by accident while fumbling around. This is what I want, to have some frozen rows and some frozen columns. But I don't know how I got here!

[Freezing Panes2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCaeV.png)

Just to add, before I made this post, I visited Libreoffice's help page at https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Freezing_Rows_or_Columns_as_Headers
I definitely did not do the stuff they said, such as 'view - freeze cells'. So I honestly don't know how I got to Freezing Panes2. But Freezing Panes2 is the result I want, so I hope someone can help! Please tell me the steps to get to Freezing Panes2 so that I can apply it to my other appointment book sheets!

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

*View -> Split Window* should fix the problem.

The window gets split by dragging the dark line as you described.  There's still only one sheet, but it's shown in multiple views.  This feature can be used to compare various parts of the sheet side by side.

https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Split_Window

To freeze rows 1 through 9 and column A, select cell B10 and then go to *View -> Freeze Cells -> Freeze Rows and Columns*.

https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Freezing_Rows_or_Columns_as_Headers